# xCode 4.6 - Status bar not appearing even when enabled for app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, statusbar

I started making updates to my app today. When I launch it in iOS Simulator (running xCode 4.6) the status bar is not visible during app launch (this is how I want it set, and how my app is setup in xCode) but then it is also not visible when I get to my Tab Bar Controller view and all my UIViewControllers (I have a tab based nav app).

The problem this creates is that the UIViewControllers, when displayed on a 4-inch display in iOS Simulator, it creates a small white space above the bottom Tab navigation bar (the height of which matches a status bar).  I tried reverting my app to a previous backup but still can't get this fixed.

Help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Using latest version of xCode (4.6)
iOS SDK 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this when you want the status bar to reappear:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Hope this solves it.

Comment: What file should I put that in?  My viewcontroller.m?

Comment: Yes I would put it in your viewController.m in your viewDidLoad method

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Not sure why I needed to add this code as I was sure everything worked without it.  Maybe somehow it got taken out and I just didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

OK write this line: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO];` 
in your appdelegate.m class under this method: - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` & then check.